# Can't change netmask to other than /32 for a Debian virtual machine created on google cloud platform

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, network-interface, google-cloud

I have created two virtual machines in google cloud platform both are on the same VPC 10.164.0.0/20.

One machine is configure with static IP 10.164.0.2, and the other machine is configure with static IP 10.164.0.4

I have made sure to create a firewall to allow all traffic in that subnet to make troubleshooting easier.

When I log in into the machines I try ping one each other and **it fails.**

**1st VM Machine**

The host is a Debian 10 buster imaged with existing image provided by GCP.

print out of ip -a gives:

```
2: ens4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1460 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 42:01:0a:a4:00:04 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.164.0.4/32 brd 10.164.0.4 scope global dynamic ens4
       valid_lft 3384sec preferred_lft 3384sec
    inet6 fe80::4001:aff:fea4:4/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

[image: Network interfaces in GCP]

cat /etc/network/interfaces

```
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

# Cloud images dynamically generate config fragments for newly
# attached interfaces. See /etc/udev/rules.d/75-cloud-ifupdown.rules
# and /etc/network/cloud-ifupdown-helper. Dynamically generated
# configuration fragments are stored in /run:
source-directory /run/network/interfaces.d
```

**2nd VM Machine**

The host is running FreeBSD 12.2 imaged using an iso image uploaded by me.

print out of ip -a (in fact it is ifconfig as it runs FreeBSD):

```
vtnet0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1460
        description: WAN
        options=800b8<VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,JUMBO_MTU,VLAN_HWCSUM,LINKSTATE>
        ether 42:01:0a:a4:00:02
        inet6 fe80::4001:aff:fea4:2%vtnet0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1
        inet 10.164.0.2 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 10.164.0.255
        media: Ethernet 10Gbase-T <full-duplex>
        status: active
        nd6 options=21<PERFORMNUD,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
```

[image: Network interfaces in GCP]

So, to conclude so far:

Both VM's are on the same subnet 10.164.0.0/20

1st machine has 10.164.0.4/**32**

2nd machine has 10.164.0.2/**24**

To me it seems like the the problem lies with the 1st machine, as it has a /32 netmask
it would not be able to access the rest of the larger subnet /24.

Tried configuring a static IP address directly by editing the /etc/network/interface file but then it fails loading the interface. It seems the interface configuration was done by google cloud platform when the vm was created.

How can I change to a static IP address or change the netmask from the GPC web UI?

How can I make both machines see each other on the same subnet?